# How to display Ajax returned data to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

i have these `javaScript functions`:
function `fetch_items` must return some data looks like this `stringvalue` at a time. and the function `extract_items($arr)` will pass vlaue to  `fetch_items`

```
    function fetch_items($id){
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?=site_url("orders/find_item")?>",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
           ajax:true,
           item_id: $id
               },
        success:function(response){
            return response;
        }
    }); 
  }

function extract_items($values) {

    var $content_set = '';
    var $items_id = $values.split(",");

    var $len = $items_id.length;

    for(var $i=0; $i<$len; $i++){
    fetch_items($items_id[$i]);

    }  
return $content_set;
}
```

And this is my `HTML` Table which i need to convert numeric `IDs` to item names which the ajax will return by taking the ID of the items.

[image]

so how to display ajax response data to the item column and convert my `ids` which now is (11,2,6,8) to there names which i extract by ajax.

any help please.

Comment: Your not trying to use the return value of `fetch_items($items_id[$i]);`? what should be the final value of `$content_set`..? This can be resolved in many ways depending on what should be the result. *"convert my ids which now is (11,2,6,8) to there names which i extract by ajax"* - How are you planning to do this..?

Comment: i have `items` table in my database which there `item_id` is 1,2,3,4 so the ajax will read one by one when this function `fetch_items($items_id[$i])` passes the value. so the ajax response one item at a time which is the extact item name. and also i would like to display it my html table when page finishes loading or at loading time.

Comment: @TJ, please see my comment.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
function fetch_items($id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?=site_url("orders/find_item")?>",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            ajax: true,
            item_id: $id
        },
        success: function (response) {
          //return response; remove this line, async return doesn't help here
          //find the respective cell and update your div here
          $(your_element).text(response)
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: when to call and where to call the Ajax function,

Comment: @Saedawke this is the success callback of ajax function. Instead of returning the value, directly update it to your website. unlike many other languages, things doesn't always work synchronously in JavaScript.

Comment: @Reza how to call function under `$(document).ready(function(){
// your code
});` and pass my value, so it is easy to update my div section immediately after the respond

Comment: Keep your code as it is, just try to use the ajax response and try to find the cell using `$id` or something. After find the cell you can update your table immediately.

Comment: @Reza, i need to get cell element by id, and then update but when document loaded so how do i convert my 'fetch_items()` to JQuery.

Comment: There is nothing to convert, put the caller function into document.ready like `$(document).ready(function(){ // caller_function });` here `extract_items($values)` will be the caller if someone else call `extract_items($values)` that would be caller, otherwise you can keep all the functionality inside document.ready.